# PHP Conditional row calculation

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I've displayed into a table like bellow:

```
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|       | Sales | Earned by date ($)|
| Name  | Code  |-------+-----+-----+
|       |       |  1    |  2  |  3  |... end of month
+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
| Jhon  |  A    |  4.5  |  7  |  2  |
| Jhon  |  B    |  1.5  |  7  |  5  |
| Jhon  |  C    |  8.2  |  4  |  4  |
| Ryan  |  A    |  4    |  6  |  3  |
| Ryan  |  B    |  5    |  7  |  2  |
| Ryan  |  C    |  2.9  |  9  |  7  |
| Jeny  |  A    |  9.1  |  3  |  4  |
| Jeny  |  B    |  5    |  5  |  6  |
| Jeny  |  C    |  7    |  6  |  3  |
+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
```

In the last row of table, I want to fill the total row value on each date based on the summary of rows that contain same sales code.

I've tried the following syntax:

```
    <?php
$data = array(
    "0" => array("name" => "Jhon", "sales_code"=>"A", "1" => 4.5, "2"=>7, "3"=>2),
    "1" => array("name" => "Jhon", "sales_code"=>"B", "1" => 1.5, "2"=>7, "3"=>5),
    "2" => array("name" => "Jhon",  "sales_code"=>"C", "1" => 8.2, "2"=>4, "3"=>4),
    "3" => array("name" => "Ryan", "sales_code"=>"A", "1" => 4, "2"=>6, "3"=>3),
    "4" => array("name" => "Ryan",  "sales_code"=>"B", "1" => 5, "2"=>7, "3"=>2),
    "5" => array("name" => "Ryan",  "sales_code"=>"C", "1" => 2.9, "2"=>9, "3"=>7),
    "6" => array("name" => "Jeny",  "sales_code"=>"A", "1" => 9.1, "2"=>3, "3"=>4),
    "7" => array("name" => "Jeny",  "sales_code"=>"B", "1" => 5, "2"=>5, "3"=>6),
    "8" => array("name" => "Jeny",  "sales_code"=>"C", "1" => 7, "2"=>6, "3"=>3),
    );


    ?>
    <table border="1" width="">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Sales code</th>
            <th colspan="3">Earned by date ($)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $a_tot = 0;
        $c_tot = 0;
        $b_tot = 0;
        foreach($data as $row){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['sales_code']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['1']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['2']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['3']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $a_tot += ($row['sales_code'] == "A" ? $row['1'] : 0);
            $b_tot += ($row['sales_code'] == "B" ? $row['2'] : 0);
            $c_tot += ($row['sales_code'] == "C" ? $row['3'] : 0);
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td><td>A</td> <td><?=$a_tot?></td> <td><?=$a_tot?></td> <td><?=$a_tot?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td><td>B</td> <td><?=$b_tot?></td> <td><?=$b_tot?></td> <td><?=$b_tot?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td><td>C</td> <td><?=$c_tot?></td> <td><?=$c_tot?></td> <td><?=$c_tot?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

But the result ended up like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|       | Sales | Earned by date ($)|
| Name  | Code  |-------+-----+-----+
|       |       |  1    |  2  |  3  |
+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
| Jhon  |  A    |  4.5  |  7  |  2  |   
| Jhon  |  B    |  1.5  |  7  |  5  | 
| Jhon  |  C    |  8.2  |  4  |  4  | 
| Ryan  |  A    |  4    |  6  |  3  |
| Ryan  |  B    |  5    |  7  |  2  | 
| Ryan  |  C    |  2.9  |  9  |  7  | 
| Jeny  |  A    |  9.1  |  3  |  4  | 
| Jeny  |  B    |  5    |  5  |  6  | 
| Jeny  |  C    |  7    |  6  |  3  | 
+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
| TOTAL +  A    |  17.6 |17.6 |17.6 | 
| TOTAL +  B    |  19   | 19  | 19  | 
| TOTAL +  C    |  14   | 14  | 14  | 
+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
```

I would like to have the result like bellow:

```
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|       | Sales | Earned by date ($)|
| Name  | Code  |-------+-----+-----+
|       |       |  1    |  2  |  3  |
+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
| Jhon  |  A    |  4.5  |  7  |  2  |   
| Jhon  |  B    |  1.5  |  7  |  5  | 
| Jhon  |  C    |  8.2  |  4  |  4  | 
| Ryan  |  A    |  4    |  6  |  3  |
| Ryan  |  B    |  5    |  7  |  2  | 
| Ryan  |  C    |  2.9  |  9  |  7  | 
| Jeny  |  A    |  9.1  |  3  |  4  | 
| Jeny  |  B    |  5    |  5  |  6  | 
| Jeny  |  C    |  7    |  6  |  3  | 
+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
| TOTAL +  A    | 17.6  | 16  |  9  | 
| TOTAL +  B    | 11.5  | 19  | 13  | 
| TOTAL +  C    | 18.1  | 19  | 14  | 
+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative, instead of hardcoding those combination figures, just create an array of those totals. Create the totals first, them present them. In other words, group them first.

```
<table border="1" width="">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Sales code</th>
        <th colspan="3">Earned by date ($)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $grand_total = array();
    foreach($data as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['sales_code']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['1']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['2']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['3']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            if(!isset($grand_total[$row['sales_code']][$i])) {
                $grand_total[$row['sales_code']][$i] = 0;
            }
            $grand_total[$row['sales_code']][$i] += $row[$i];
        }
    }   
    ?>

    <?php foreach($grand_total as $code => $total_row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        <td><?php echo $code; ?></td>
        <?php foreach($total_row as $t) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $t; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>  
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ghost, you save my day.

Comment: @HarapanHarefa sure glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

You just need more counters / variables.  If you know more about your data structure, you could make this table is a much more flexible, robust way.  But the long hand, fragile way is...

```
 <table border="1" width="">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Sales code</th>
            <th colspan="3">Earned by date ($)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $a_tot1 = 0;
        $a_tot2 = 0;
        $a_tot3 = 0;
        $c_tot1 = 0;
        $c_tot2 = 0;
        $c_tot3 = 0;
        $b_tot1 = 0;
        $b_tot2 = 0;
        $b_tot3 = 0;
        foreach($data as $row){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['sales_code']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['1']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['2']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['3']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $a_tot1 += ($row['sales_code'] == "A" ? $row['1'] : 0);
            $a_tot2 += ($row['sales_code'] == "A" ? $row['2'] : 0);
            $a_tot3 += ($row['sales_code'] == "A" ? $row['3'] : 0);
            $b_tot1 += ($row['sales_code'] == "B" ? $row['1'] : 0);
            $b_tot2 += ($row['sales_code'] == "B" ? $row['2'] : 0);
            $b_tot3 += ($row['sales_code'] == "B" ? $row['3'] : 0);
            $c_tot1 += ($row['sales_code'] == "C" ? $row['1'] : 0);
            $c_tot2 += ($row['sales_code'] == "C" ? $row['2'] : 0);
            $c_tot3 += ($row['sales_code'] == "C" ? $row['3'] : 0);
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td><td>A</td> <td><?=$a_tot1?></td> <td><?=$a_tot2?></td> <td><?=$a_tot3?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td><td>B</td> <td><?=$b_tot1?></td> <td><?=$b_tot2?></td> <td><?=$b_tot3?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td><td>C</td> <td><?=$c_tot1?></td> <td><?=$c_tot2?></td> <td><?=$c_tot3?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: If that worked for you, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but others have given the most appropriate answer because I need a code that supports dynamic content

Comment: Then state that in the question!  "If you know more about your data structure, you could make this table is a much more flexible, robust way."  Waste of everyone's time.